# Why child Styled-components is not applying styles?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a `Notification` component  :

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import Wrapper from "./Wrapper"
import context from "./context"
import Close from "./Close"

const Notification = ({ children }) => {

    const { type } = useContext(context)

    return (<Wrapper type={type}>
        <Close /> {// This component does not apply styles !!}
        {children}
    </Wrapper>)
}

export default Notification
```

My `Wrapper` :

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const Wrapper = styled.div`
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
      right:0;
      margin-right:1.2em;
      margin-bottom:1.2em;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding:15px;
      min-width:350px;
      min-height:100px;
      border-radius:20px;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 30px 0px ${({ type }) => pickShadowColor(type)}}`

const pickShadowColor = (type) => {
    switch (type) {
        case "info": return "rgba(51,153,255,0.3)";
        case "warning": return "rgba(255,157,0,0.3)";
        case "success": return "rgba(0,216,0,0.3)";
        case "error": return "rgba(255,0,0,0.3)";
        default: return "rgba(190,190,190,0.3)";
    }
}

export default Wrapper
```

#### The result is :

[image: github-issue]

The problem is with `Close` component while it has a custom style but it still shows the default style of `button`.

`Close` component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from './Button';

const Close = () => (
    <Button>close</Button>
)

export default Close;
```

and the styled `Button` :

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Button = styled.button({
    'background-color': 'red'
})
```

### Expected Behavior

The button should be `red`.

### Actual Behavior

The button has a default style.

### Additional Info

- Navigator: Chrome.
- The button does not accept any styles.

Comment: This code works for me, can you make a reproducible example? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-forked-19t49?file=/index.js

Comment: Did you run it on `Chrome` ?

Comment: Did you open the link? Yes it I checked on chrome how, why its related?

Comment: Yes, I checked the link and I'm wondering what's the issue exactly, I'll reproduce the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem its on `box-shadow`. You are missing a `;` and have an extra `{`

Change it FROM:

```js
box-shadow: 0px 4px 30px 0px ${({ type }) => pickShadowColor(type)}}`;
```

TO:

```js
box-shadow: 0px 4px 30px 0px ${({ type }) => pickShadowColor(type)};`;
```

The complete style:

```js
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  min-width: 350px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 30px 0px ${({ type }) => pickShadowColor(type)};
`;
```

Comment: Exactly,  I fixed the issue today. The developer who voted down should apologize to you.